# Альтернативы межпроцессному взаимодействию? plugin architecture?

Tags: архитектура, плагин

Предположим я собираюсь написать Клиент-Сервер-БД.
Я новичок-любитель, писать буду только для себя и мало чем ограничен.
Я мог бы впихнуть все это в одну программу, но в итоге клиентов, серверов, БД может оказаться несколько, новые будут появляться, старые отмирать, что-то может оказаться на другой машине в сети.
Я понимаю принцип межпроцессного взаимодействия - написать разные программы и связать их.
Важна скорость/надежность обмена данными, но мне сложно оценить какие будут задержки в этом случае.
Есть ли еще какие-либо решения?

**Дополнение:** "плагинная архитектура" - это не то, что мне нужно? Одна шина/ядро, куда подключаются сервера/клиенты/БД, реализованные как плагины, и общаются между собой?
Правильно-ли я понял, что плагин - это фактически dll, и ни каких ограничений не будет, т.е. это может быть полноценная программа, например многооконный клиент?

Comment: "на другой машине в сети" тогда никаких других вариантов кроме сокета в принципе нет

Comment: @ andreymal, как я понял, pipes можно использовать в этом случае. Кроме того, я могу использовать несколько методов.

Comment: pipes через сеть не работают.

Comment: Если это разные процессы, то независимо от конкретной реализации (даже если на одной машине и используете pipes), это все равно будет межпроцессное взаимодействие по определению. Так что вообще непонятно, альтернативу чему вы ищете. Что вы называете `межпроцессным взаимодействием`?

Comment: @Roman Konoval, есть две крайности: все в одной программе и три разные программы. Я ищу золотую середину, т.к. боюсь задержек в передаче данных между отдельными программами. Межпроцессным взаимодействием я называю то, что называется так официально.

Comment: Если вы хотите «другую машину в сети», то крайность «разные программы» это единственный возможный вариант

Comment: @andreymal, да, я понимаю, но это - "если". Если мне это понадобится, то я вынесу это в отдельную программу.

Comment: imho если пишете для себя, то проблем со скоростью при использовании sockets не возникнет